# How to use ASMX WebService interface created through connected service in dot Net Core 2 in VS2017

Tags: c#, web, service, .net-core, asmx

So i have created a reference to a old ASMX Web Service inside of dotnet core. It created a object file, however I am unable to access the web service methods directly. It did create a interface that contains those methods that I need to access.

Some of the generated code

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace LegacyClient
{


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://echromics.corp", ConfigurationName="LegacyClient.ViewWSSoap")]
    public interface ViewWSSoap
    {

 [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://echromics.corp/SCADA_Request", ReplyAction="*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(IGProcessData))]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<LegacyClient.Packet> SCADA_RequestAsync(string Input1, string Input2, string Input3, string Input4, string Input5, string Input6, string Input7, string Input8, string Input9, string Input10, int BONumber, string LiteID, string RequestFunction, string Origin, string SecurityToken);
      }
```

Comment: Im not entirely sure what code to show. The generated files? Thats thousands upon thousands of lines.

Comment: Hmm, yes, but don't you have a client class somewhere? And; what do you mean by `object file`?

Comment: Right now the client is a empty RESTful API Get method. By object file i mean when i added the connected service it created a Reference.cs file, which is generated code.

Comment: Yes, normally it contains a helper class which contains a concrete implementation to connect with the service.

Comment: Ah, yes, that looks good.... do you have a `ViewWSSoapClass` somewhere (I think that's how the helper class is named through naming conventions)

Comment: I dont think so, just the interface

Comment: I take that back I have a ViewWSSoapClient class, that seems to take a EndpointCOnfiguration object as a parameter

Comment: and that did the trick, thanks! Finding the client class let me do what i needed to do

Comment: You're welcome :-)